# How do I call static method for a generic type in a class?

Tags: c#

```
interface TerminationCondition
{
    static bool IsSatisfied(some parameters);
}
```

Let's say some classes A and B implement this interface.

Some other class C has a generic type:

```
class C<termCondition> where termCondition : TerminationCondition
```

I need to call IsSatisfied from C accordingly, whether I have passed A or B for the generic type. For some reason it is not possible termCondition.IsSatisfied().

To summarize, the question is How do I call static method for a generic type in a class?

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible.

In fact, you can't have static methods in an interface at all.

Answer (score 2):

Since `termCondition` is required to be of type `TerminationCondition`, you could simple have `IsSatisfied` be an instance method of the classes that implement that interface.  There's no need to have that method be static at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool result = C<TerminationCondition>.IsSatisfied();
```

As @SLaks pointed out, you can't have static methods in an interface. Having them in a generic type tends to be awkward.

@Austin also makes a good point.

You can have static generic methods (normally in non-generic types); these have their uses.

```
public static bool IsSatisfied<T>(T condition)
    where T: TerminationCondition
```